# Trigger created with compilation errors for Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I tried to create code using Oracle trigger syntax, but there is a warning:

> trigger created with compilation errors

Here is the code. I want to raise an error when the price in table `itemtype` is set to over four times the minimum old price. How can I do that?

I tried to fix the previous problem! I created the trigger successfully, but it only works when insert, the "mutating table" error still occurs when I was tring to update the price on table itemType. How can I change my code to make it also works when updating?

```
    CREATE or replace TRIGGER tr_price before insert or update on itemType for each row
    declare minimum float;
    begin
      select min(price)
      into minimum
      from itemType;
      if :new.price > 4*minimum
        then
        raise_application_error (-20000,'new price can not over 4 times min old price');
      END IF;
    end;
    /
```

Comment: When you get that warning, the first thing to do is to find out what the error was. In SQL\*Plus or SQL Developer (or, I assume, in Toad and other interfaces), one way is to issue the command `show errors` (no need for semi-colon since this is not a SQL statement). This will tell you WHAT the compilation error was. Please run that and edit your post to add that information.

Comment: In this case, I suspect the error is a "mutating table" error; a trigger is not allowed, in its code, to `select` from the same table on which it (the trigger) is supposed to act. But it is better if you tell us what the error is.

Comment: thanks mathguy, i run the show error and it shows that "mutating table" error! but i dunno how to fix it : ( @mathguy

Comment: From my earlier comment:  ...  Please run that **and edit your post to add that information.** Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As clarified in the Comments (or, if you answer my request, as edited in the post itself), you are running into the "mutating table" error. And you would like to know how to fix it.

Alas, this is not a programming error. It is a **logical** problem (which Oracle chose not to ignore, by rising the "mutating table" error).

Oracle is a multi-user environment, and SQL allows you to insert/alter/delete many rows in one transaction. Both of these things are GOOD, but they mean you can't do things like what you are trying to do.

What is the "old" minimum price? Suppose you had 20 rows already, and the minimum price was $55. You add one more row with the price $50. Now you try to add another row with price $210. What is "the old minimum"? $220? Why, because the row with the price of $50 was inserted, but not committed yet? Or is it $200? What if, in the same transaction, but later in your code, you DELETE the row with the $55 price and the next lowest is $60 - shouldn't you allow prices up to $240?

Then compound this problem: you insert a few rows, but you don't commit yet. Then someone else inserts (or updates or deletes) in the same table, and they commit their transaction. Now you want to commit. Shouldn't the "check" be performed again, at the end of the transaction, and not "for each row"?

The whole idea of tying the behavior of DML statements to data in the table, as it exists at one time or another (and as may change in the middle of your transaction, as caused either by your own other activity or by the activity of other users at the same time), is something you must understand clearly, and discuss with the "business managers" or "business users" who may not know or understand SQL, but who must understand this issue and who must come up with **logical** requirements. Only allowing inserts where the price is "no more than four times the old minimum" is not internally consistent, and Oracle, wisely, does not allow you to do something that wouldn't make sense.

So - the short answer is "you can't fix the solution, because the solution is not broken, the problem itself is broken." You must fix the problem first.